How to use AVPlayerViewController with MobileVLCKit?
I'm trying to use native controls with another player than the Apple's one, because as we know the native player from Apple doesn't work with MKV files, I have to use another player like MobileVLCKit.
I tried different ways but nothing work well, in a fisrt way I'm able to see the video but not the controls and in a second way I'm able to see the controls but not the video (I have the sound)
I saw that some Apps on the store are already do it but I don't know how they do.
class VLCPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {
    private var mediaPlayer: VLCMediaPlayer?
    var mediaURL: URL = URL(string: bunnyURL)!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupVLCPlayer(with: mediaURL)
    }

    private func setupVLCPlayer(with url: URL) {
        // Initialize VLCMediaPlayer
        let media = VLCMedia(url: url)
        mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()
        mediaPlayer?.media = media

        // Set the VLC drawable to the view's layer
        mediaPlayer?.drawable = view.layer
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        mediaPlayer?.play()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Stop VLC playback when the view disappears
        mediaPlayer?.stop()
    }
}

struct VLCPlayerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var mediaURL: URL

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> VLCPlayerViewController {
        let controller = VLCPlayerViewController()
        controller.mediaURL = mediaURL
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: VLCPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        // Handle updates if necessary
    }
}

